# 'RestClient' is a namespace but its used like a type - package issue

Tags: c#, restsharp, rest

Ive removed sensitive data but am getting this issue when trying to make an API request, although I have the relevant packages installed. Why would this be?

```
using System;
using IronXL; 
using RestClient;
using Rest;
using Newtonsoft;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using RestSharp.Validation;
    public static void APIRequest()
        
    {
        var client = new RestClient("");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.evolutionx.v1+json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer  ");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

    }
```

Comment: What's the package you're using?

Comment: @RemarkLima Im using restclient.net

Comment: @ADyson I have put the namespace before the restclient and am met with this: The type or namepsace name 'restClient' does not exist in the namespace 'MYnamespace'

Comment: `I have put the namespace`...which namespace exactly? You didn't say which namespace it actually comes from? Also you seem to have referenced RestClient and Restsharp in your code, which sound like they probably do very similar things...do you actually need them both?

Comment: @ADyson rest sharp is responsible for the methods etc while the name space of "using RestClient;" is also in the code but its greyed out? Does this mean it cannot be used?

Comment: No, it means that currently you aren't actually using any objects from it in your code. (If you used anything from it, it would then be normal colour. The IDE is just trying to help you spot redundant code. ) So actually the solution, as I suggested in my answer below, is probably to just remove that line from your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using RestClient.net, it looks like you need to instantiate using

`var client = new RestClient.Net.Client();`

So the class is `Client`.

The details of how to setup the class is here:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net

Note the how to start

```
var client = new Client(new NewtonsoftSerializationAdapter(), new Uri("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/"));
var response = await client.GetAsync<List<RestCountry>>();
```

or using .NET Core serialisation

```
var client = new Client(new Uri("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/"));
var response = await client.GetAsync<List<RestCountry>>();
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying this solution out but am still abit stuck, APIs are completely new to me.    and I am still receving errors

Comment: @AlexQuinn the Rest API you are consuming should be mappable to a class... So if you browse to "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/" you'll see a JSON string with a load of country data. You can create class with the same property names / types and then map to a list of those. In you question, you're not hitting a URL so will not get access to any data?? What's the error?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Client' could not be found

Comment: That should be `var client = new RestClient.Net.Client();` as per the first part of the answer - or add the using statement at the top of your class, `using RestClient.Net;`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
using RestClient;
```

makes `RestClient` a known namespace in your code. C# will then assume that any references to `RestClient` refer to that namespace, unless you specifically say otherwise.

If `RestClient` really is a class, then you'll have to specify its namespace in front of it

e.g.

```
new RelevantNamespace.RestClient("")
```

to differentiate it from the namespace. I would guess it's the `RestClient` class from `RestSharp`, so probably new `RestSharp.RestClient("")` makes sense.

---

On the other hand, you said in the comments that the `RestClient` namespace is greyed out in the IDE. This means you are you not using anything from it. Therefore to solve your problem can you can simply remove that `using RestClient;` statement from your file.

You probably also don't need the RestClient.net package in general, since RestSharp already does a very similar job.

Comment: I have just copied the request over from postman into C#, im new to this so its a learning curve, I have included the using RestClient; but it seems to be greyed out and the answer you have given throws and error also

Comment: If I remove the restclient line the code does still not get resolved and the namespace error remains

Comment: @AlexQuinn that's not true - demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gsFLuu . However my demo does have a **different** error about the `Rest` namepsace - but that might be just because I didn't install a package that you've installed in your version. Are you sure it's the exact same error? Did you re-build your code after you made the change to remove the greyed-out namespace?

Comment: But in fact I can reduce the demo down, removing all the un-used namspaces and end up with this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f86Dae (you may not be able to remove them all of course - as the class you showed in the question is incomplete you could be using them elsewhere, but I don't know. The point is to show that removing the RestClient namespace definitely solves the error.)

Comment: this brings back the error 'restclient' is a namespace but is used like a type' issue

Comment: That's impossible. If you don't have `using RestClient` in your code then you can't have that error. The demo proves it. Are you sure you're building the code correctly?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DzlpHG this is my code, as i said, this is all new to me

Comment: Apologies, this now works, thank you for your help :)